# Django in Lighttpd + FCGI on Ubuntu - rewrites stop working when I enable a second site

Tags: django, ubuntu, lighttpd, fastcgi

I've got lighttp configured to start and serve django via fastcgi on ubuntu. When I have only a single site enabled (via ubuntu's apache-like conf-available, conf-enabled mechanism), everything runs beautifully. When I enable a second site, my url rewrites seem to stop working correctly, though the fcgi processes are started and serving data. Here's my configuration:

`conf-available/10-example.conf`

```
$HTTP["host"] == "example.com" {
    var.virt_name = "example"
    include "includes/incl-fastcgi.conf"
}
```

`includes/incl-fastcgi.conf`

```
global {
    server.modules += ("mod_rewrite",
                   "mod_fastcgi")
}

var.site_folder = "/" + virt_name
var.site_root = server_root + site_folder
var.socket = server_root + "/.handles/" + virt_name + ".socket"
server.document-root = site_root

fastcgi.server = (
    "/django.fcgi" => (
        "main" => (
            "socket" => socket,
            "bin-path" => "/etc/lighttpd/scripts/fcgi.sh",
            "bin-environment" => ( "VIRT" => virt_name, ),
            "check-local" => "disable",
            "min-procs" => 1,
            "max-procs" => 1,
            "allow-x-send-file" => "enable",
        ),
    ),
)

alias.url = (
    "/media/admin" => "/usr/share/python-support/python-django/django/contrib/admin/media", #why the hell does it live here?
)

url.rewrite-once = (
    "^(/media.*)$" => "$1",
    "^/favicon\.ico$" => "/media/favicon.ico",
    "^/robots\.txt$" => "/robots.txt",
    "^(/.*)$" => "/django.fcgi$1",
)
```

When I enable the second site, everything is identical except that now there's a second link to a (slightly modified) copy of `10-example.conf` in conf-enabled. When this happens, my sites fail with this django-served error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://example.com/django.fcgi/[the url I requested]
```

I'm not sure why enabling another site should break the existing setup. I believe the host-based syntax should isolate any changes to that specific host, but it does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone in the future looks at this question, I believe the answer was that it's fixed in version 1.4.20 or later and the server was running v1.4.19 since that's what Ubuntu's repository had.

Answer (score 2):

Did you set [FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#force-script-name) to "" in settings.py?

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME=""
```

Comment: Keep it there because that's actually required anyway ;)

Comment: It's not actually required anymore if the rest of your settings are properly configured.